# Rails 5 - How to sort has_many associations list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sorting, ruby-on-rails-5

In rails 5 and in `postgresql`, I want to sort a list based on `created_at: :desc`.

Model structure is like,
models/review.rb

```
has_many :comments
has_many :commented_users, :through=>:comments, :source=>:user
```

In views, I want to display list of users based on `created_at (DESC)` date and this field is from `comments` table

Controller query is like,

```
review = Review.find_by_id(params[:id])
comments = review.commented_users
```

If I give `order` for `review.commented_users` then obviously it will sort `User`, how can I sort users based on `Comment`?

Review fields are,

```
=> #<Review id: nil, user_id: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Comment fields are,

```
=> #<Comment id: nil, review_id: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

User fields are,

```
=> #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, inactive: false, password_updated_at: nil, active: true, reviews_count: 0, notification_seen_at: nil, deleted_at: nil, status: "pending">
```

Please help me to solve this sorting issue and I am new to `postgresql`

Comment: Here again `id` will take from `User` model not from `Comment`.

Comment: there is some issue with association

Comment: Can you show your Review fields and relationship ?

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: @ShruthiR i think `commented_users` will also return `users` array am i right?

Comment: Yes. And `comments` will return `comment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the distinct from your association

```
has_many :commented_users, through: :comments, source: :user
```

You can validate the uniqueness of user with below code

```
validates :review_id, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}
```

And Finally try below query for getting sorted record by comment tables created at.

```
Review.includes(comments: :user).find_by_id(params[:id]).commented_users.order("comments.created_at")
```

Comment: How can I get `commented_users` without any relation? Right now I am getting it based on `comments`

Comment: What you want , comments or user ?

Comment: You have to post proper questions. let me check once again

Comment: I want users based on comment's date. Latest commented user should display first.

Comment: Can you please post which association you used in comments model ?

Comment: `belongs_to :user` and  `belongs_to :review`

Comment: I updated my answer. please try it and let me know is it working

Comment: You are again sorting the users here.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. just updated my answer. please check now :)

Comment: `PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

Comment: Did you used `Select ` in query ?

Comment: give me few moments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162733/discussion-between-vishal-and-shruthi-r).

Comment: Please come in chat room